# redux-form infinite loop when setting a date in initialValues

Tags: infinite-loop, redux-form

I get an infinite loop of @@redux-form/INITIALIZE messages when I try to initialise the value of a fabric ui datepicker field

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { bookingform } = state;
  return {
    initialValues: { date: new Date()},
    bookingform
  };
}
```

If I replace new Date() with "" then no loop - but then no initialisation.
React Newb

Update. Date() generates a different value each time it is called. Is that upsetting redux-form in some way? I have worked around he problem by setting the default directly in the fabric ui component for the time being

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mapStateToProps` is called every time when it's are updated, so if you pass `new Date()` as params it is predictably that your connected component will rerender each millisecond.

Move `new Date()` to variable and than pass it to `mapStateToProps`.

```
const now = new Date();

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { bookingform } = state;
  return {
    initialValues: { date: now },
    bookingform
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export default Example = reduxForm({
  form: 'example',
  enableReinitialize: false  // set it to false
})(Example);
```